# I want to take images with a framerate of 30 fps during 30 minutes using thonny (python)

Tags: picamera

I have the Raspberry pi camera v 2.1 and I want to take photos for 30 minutes at a speed of 30 fps or less, but I want to be able to vary it. So far I have achieved it with "picamera" and using camera.capture. I have seen in other answers that using camera.capture_sequence, but I can't save them in a folder. If someone can help me I would be infinitely grateful.

Comment: `I have achieved it` - congratulations, what's the problem?

Comment: I got it with camera.capture only at 1-3 fps rate. But I want much higher speed

Comment: video is 30 fps ... just saying

Answer (score 1):

30 photos per second won't be possible on a Pi. This is something you can expect from a high-end digital camera like [Canon EOS R3](https://www.dpreview.com/news/5600618654/canon-eos-r3-will-shoot-30-fps-raw-bursts-with-oversampled-4k-and-8-stop-is), not from a cheap camera module with MIPI interface driven by Linux.

Comment: and what is the maximum speed I could get?

Comment: 1-3 fps at a guess